# Angular 7 : api can't load with one click ( two click needed)

Tags: angular, api

I hope that my english it will allow you to understand my problem.

I'm trying to load datas from API, but I need to click 2 times before view data.

It looks like I need to load datas two times to update it 
On the first click I get datas, but are not updated.

I create an event (mouseenter) for 'prefetch' but this solution It's horrible.

Some help?

Thanks

HTML (very simple file)

```
<form  [formGroup]="getRates"><div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <select
                class="form-control"
                name="bases"
                formControlName="bases"
                placeholder="Select Currency"
               ><option *ngFor="let item of bases" [value]="item.curr">{{item.curr}}</option>
              </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <input
                name="date"
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Datepicker"
                formControlName="date"
                bsDatepicker>
          </div>
        </div></div><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" (click)="showConfig()" (mouseenter)="showConfig()">Get rates</button></form>
```

TS (here I set the value of the table)

```
     import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import{ ConfigService, Config } from './config.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-form',
      templateUrl: './form.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
    })
    export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
      bases: any[];
      date: any;
      day: number;
      mounth: number;
      year: number;
      config: Config;
      getRates: FormGroup;
      currency: string;
      i: number;
      error: any;
      constructor(private configService: ConfigService) { }
      ngOnInit() {
        this.getRates = new FormGroup({
          'date': new FormControl(),
           'bases': new FormControl(),
         });
        this.bases = this.configService.tableData;
      }
      public showConfig() {
        if (this.getRates.value.bases) {
          this.currency = this.getRates.get('bases').value;
        }
        if (this.getRates.value.date) {
          this.day = this.getRates.get('date').value.getDate();
          this.mounth = this.getRates.get('date').value.getMonth() + 1;
          this.year = this.getRates.get('date').value.getFullYear();
        }
        this.date = `${this.year}-${this.mounth}-${this.day}` ;
        console.log(this.currency, this.getRates.value.date);
        this.configService.configUrl = `https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/${this.date}?base=${this.currency}`;
        this.configService.getConfig()
            .subscribe(
              (data: Config) => this.config = { ...data },
              error => this.error = error
            );
            this.i = 0;
              for (const value of this.bases) {
                if (this.config) {
                this.i++;
                this.configService.tableData[this.i - 1].buy = this.config.rates[value.curr] - (this.config.rates[value.curr] / 100 * 5);
                this.configService.tableData[this.i - 1].sell = this.config.rates[value.curr] + (this.config.rates[value.curr] / 100 * 5);
                }
              }
      }preFetchData() {
        this.showConfig();
      }
    }
```

SERVICE TS ( here I get the API data)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';



export interface Config {
  base: string;
  date: string;
  rates: number[];

}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigService {

  config: Config;
  rates = ['EUR', 'USD', 'GBP', 'AUD', 'CAD', 'JPY'];
  tableData = [
    {'curr': 'GBP', 'buy': 1, 'sell': 1},
    {'curr': 'EUR', 'buy': 1, 'sell': 1},
    {'curr': 'USD', 'buy': 1, 'sell': 1},
    {'curr': 'AUD', 'buy': 1, 'sell': 1},
    {'curr': 'CAD', 'buy': 1, 'sell': 1},
    {'curr': 'JPY', 'buy': 1, 'sell': 1},
  ];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   }

  configUrl = '';

  getConfig() {
    return this.http.get<Config>(this.configUrl);
  }
}
```

Console log

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With HttpClient you get a promise by default, so I've add  () => this.preFetchData() And I moved the code in another function.

here the code

```
this.configService.getConfig()
        .subscribe(
          (data: Config) => this.config = { ...data },
          error => this.error = error,
          () => this.preFetchData()
        );


  }
  preFetchData() {
    this.i = 0;
        for (const value of this.bases) {
          if (this.config) {
          this.i++;
          this.configService.tableData[this.i - 1].buy = this.config.rates[value.curr] - (this.config.rates[value.curr] / 100 * 5);
          this.configService.tableData[this.i - 1].sell = this.config.rates[value.curr] + (this.config.rates[value.curr] / 100 * 5);
          console.log(this.currency, this.date, this.configService.tableData[this.i - 1].buy);
          }
        }
  }
```